# Sass partials can not reuse imports from main

Tags: css, sass

I have a main.scss

```
@import "./base";
@import "./partners-offers";
@import "./stage";
```

base.scss

```
@import "../../../../../sass/tools/mixins";
@import "../../../../../sass/tools/mq";
@import "~sass-mq/mq";
@import "../../../../../sass/base/base";
@import "../../../../../sass/base/typography";
```

the partial partners.scss relies on those imports from base.scss but apparantly can not use them - my build returns an error. If I import everything needed directly from the partial - it works. why is this?

Comment: Where are you importing _partners.scss? Or do you mean "./partners-offers"? If you're loading _partners.scss before _base.scss, your _base.scss imports won't be available to _partners.scss. If that doesn't help - what exact error do you see when you try to compile?